# Mysql trigger replace row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to see if can I use mysql to manage a little stock.

table A contain all the movements:
`art_code, qty_load, qty_unload, date`

table B with the existence:
`art_code, total_load, total_unload, available, date`

I've created a trigger: (after update on)

```
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES(NEW.ART_CODE, TOTAL_LOAD, TOTAL_UNLOAD, TOTAL_LOAD-TOTAL_UNLOAD, NOW());
```

but after the first correct run it says a row already exists, how could I replace the old row with the new row?

Comment: Use `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command. It will help you to insert and to update existed records using one statement.

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)